# milliwatt-hour meter

Tags: power, current-measurement, power-meter

I am looking for a way to design something that can tell me the cumulative power draw of a circuit -- the same concept as a [Kill-a-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html), but measuring mWh rather than KWh. An added bonus would be the capability of generating graphs to show usage over time.

I'm dealing with ~3.5 Volts, current in the low mW range. Time periods to be logged range from a few minutes to a few days.

Comment: A [suitable multimeter](https://www.gossenmetrawatt.com/english/produkte/metrahitenergy.htm) can do it. This one also has PC interface and logging memory.

Comment: This is a shopping question. You should reword it to something more general to avoid closing.

Comment: OK, thanks... but a $900 device is very much overkill for my application (not to mention my wallet!).

Comment: Please be more clear. What voltage range, and current range are you intending to measure.

Comment: 3.5 Volts, current in the low mW range. Time periods ranging from a few minutes to a few days.

Comment: Please update your question, rather than use comments, when there are new facts to add. It is easier for folks to understand.

Comment: Approximately how accurate do you need? I am looking at "Time periods ranging from a few minutes to a few days." and thinking about timer accuracy and precision for the integration. So what level of precision for time?

Comment: @gbulmer - it would have to be fairly accurate. I am trying to extrapolate to a year's worth of battery usage.

Comment: Okay. So is this for measuring power use for MCU-based systems? I ask because MCU-based systems which have year+ battery life typically have very uneven power use. They might 'sleep' using very little power most of the time (µA or less), and wake up very briefly (sub millisecond) to do some work when the power use might rise by 10-1000x. Does that approximately characterise your requirements?

Comment: Do they sample and sum or integrate and count?

Comment: @gbulmer - exactly so. I would like to sample a number of hours while running thru the various usage cycles in order to get an estimate of the power draw during typical use.

Comment: Zeke, you are providing lots of information in your comments. Probably enough to explain what you want, and so avoid the question being closed. If you want the question to be taken off hold, instead of putting information in comments, put it into the question.

Comment: Here is an application note showing how ST approached a very similar problem http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00031738.pdf

Comment: @Zeke did you ever find a good solution to this question? let me know details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the supply voltage will be constant for this test, if you convert the current to a voltage, follow that with a low pass filter, then sample well above Nyquist for the filter, you need only perform numerical integration of the voltage samples (by summing, trapezoid, Simpson's Rule etc.). Easy-peasy. The faster you sample in relation to the LPF cutoff frequency the less sophisticated your integration algorithm need be for a given accuracy.

The LPF will smear out over time any sharp pulses of current, but as long as the DC gain is 1 it will not affect the average mAh calculation. So if you have a LPF cutoff of (say) 100Hz, you could sample at 1kHz, do simple trapezoidal integration and get a nice number ramping upward as the device runs.

The only gotcha I can think of is that the bit width of the integration number (or mantissa if it's a float or double) should be equal to the number of significant bits in the current measurement + log2(sample rate) + log2(seconds in your test).

So if you're measuring the current to 12 bits, and taking measurements at 1kHz for 1 hour, you'd need 12 + 10 + 12 = 34 bits, so a double precision float would be required or a 64-bit integer.